# What does a ReactFragment from "react" mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-fragment

I was looking through a `.tsx` code that looked something like below.

```js
import React, { Fragment, ReactFragment } from "react";

// ...
export interface PageProps {
   children: ReactFragment;
   commandBar: reactFragment;
   // ...
}
    
export default page(props: PageProps) {
   return(
      <Fragment>
        // ...
      </Fragment>
   );
}
```

I roughly know what a `React.Fragment` is.
We can use either `<></>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or `<Fragment></Fragment>` based on the import sugaring, to group react elements.

So, my question is how does `ReactFragment` work here?
Is it just to indicate that `children` or `commandBar` is of a `React.Fragment` type?

In that case, why not use `React.Fragment` itself?
Googling throwed results for `React.Fragment` only.

Comment: I haven't found ReactFragment from "react". https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react/src

Comment: @spycbanda Because it is not part of React. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it just to indicate that `children` or `commandBar` is of a `React.Fragment` type?

Yes.

> In that case, why not use `React.Fragment` itself?

`React.Fragment` is not a type but a value. If you used it, you will see an compile error like this:

```
'Fragment' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below screenshot.

[image]

`ReactFragment` is one of the valid values for `ReactNode` which intern can be `Array<ReactNode>` so you can have a valid return as `ReactFragment` i.e. `<></>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` for your component.

```
import React, { ReactFragment } from 'react';

function MyComp(): ReactFragment {
    //it can return any of boolean, null, undefined, ReactChild, ReactFragment
    return (
        <></> 
    )
}
```

Here we specifically define the type to be a `ReactFragment`. Even if you return `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `ReactChild`, `ReactFragment` it will accept as it extends `Array<ReactNode>`.

In nutshell `ReactFragment` is a type that a component can return.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L238

Comment: The question is over ReactFragment and not React.Fragment. Read the question clearly.

Comment: Thanks for that! But that is all about React.Fragment and I have mentioned that I knew that concept. How do I relate your anwser to ReactFragment?

Answer (score 1):

`ReactFragment` is a type (e.g. `ReactNode` can also be a `ReactFragment`) where `Fragment` is the pattern in `react` that lets you return grouped children.